# C/C++ threads magic difference in condition

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, conditional-statements, mutex

I wanted to write simple multithread app in C/C++. Function funProducent produces 100 values and if random generated value is in given range, char is added to buffer. Function funKonzument comsumes values from buffer. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_LIMIT 20

struct struktura{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t bufferNotFull;
    pthread_cond_t bufferNotEmpty;
    int bufferIndex;
    char * buffer;
    int junk;
};

void * funProducent(void *arg){
    struktura * data = (struktura *) arg;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&data->mutex);
        if(data->bufferIndex == BUFFER_LIMIT - 1){
            pthread_cond_wait(&data->bufferNotFull, &data->mutex);
        }
        int randomValue = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        if( randomValue < 13 ){
            data->buffer[++data->bufferIndex] = 'a';
            printf("%2d : Producent at index %d added %c\n", i, data->bufferIndex, data->buffer[data->bufferIndex]);
            pthread_cond_signal(&data->bufferNotEmpty);
        } else {
            data->junk++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&data->mutex);
        i++;
    }
    printf("producent is done\n");
}

void * funKonzument(void *arg){
    struktura * data = (struktura *) arg;
    int i = 0;
    while (i + data->junk < 100) {  
        printf("%d\n", i + data->junk);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&data->mutex);
        if(data->bufferIndex < 0){
            pthread_cond_wait(&data->bufferNotEmpty, &data->mutex);
        }
        printf("%2d : Konzument at index %d consumed %c\n", i, data->bufferIndex, data->buffer[data->bufferIndex]);
        data->bufferIndex--;
        pthread_cond_signal(&data->bufferNotFull);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&data->mutex);
        i++;
    }
    printf("konzument is done\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

pthread_t threadProducent, threadKonzument;
struktura threadData;
threadData.buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_LIMIT);
threadData.bufferIndex = -1;
threadData.bufferNotFull = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
threadData.bufferNotEmpty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
threadData.mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
threadData.junk = 0;

pthread_create(&threadProducent, NULL, funProducent, &threadData);
pthread_create(&threadKonzument, NULL, funKonzument, &threadData);

pthread_join(threadProducent, NULL);
pthread_join(threadKonzument, NULL);

free(threadData.buffer);
pthread_mutex_destroy(&threadData.mutex);
pthread_cond_destroy(&threadData.bufferNotFull);
pthread_cond_destroy(&threadData.bufferNotEmpty);
return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this code, sometimes it stucks in funKonzument at this line:

```
pthread_cond_wait(&data->bufferNotEmpty, &data->mutex);
```

But...when I change condition in funProducent method from:

```
if( randomValue < 13 )
```

to

```
if( randomValue > 8 )
```

everything works fine. Is anyone able to explain me what magic difference is between this two conditions?

Comment: You're retrieving a random number from 100, and checking if it's below 13, which it has a ~10% chance of being, whereas when you are checking for it being above 8, you've got a 90% chance of it being correct. I'd say you haven't got your thread running correctly, or perhaps it's just very slow. You should try to attach your debugger and step through the code and see what's going on. It's likely you have some deadlock going on, which happens rarely but is more visible when the value isn't added

Comment: Also consider ditching `pthread` and just use `std::thread` and `std::mutex` instead.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about C++ rather than C? Except for some omitted `struct` specifiers you are using no C++ specific features or standard library at all.

Comment: in variable randomValue should be values from 1 to 20, so probability of value greater than 8 should be the same to probability of value less than 13, shouldn´t it?

Comment: It sort of suggests that `rand()` is not very random (a known issue). Also this is really C code. Nearly everything you do has a better C++ alternative. `std::vector`, `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, `std::conditional_variable`, `std::random`

Comment: Also your `funProducent()` stops after a hundred numbers. If the `funKonzument()` is in the condition variable at this time there is no way to release it. So its can get stuck (because the `pthread_cond_signal()` is only conditionally called in `funProducent()`

Comment: You are also not protecting yourself agaist spurious wakes on the `pthread_cond_wait`calls. "_Spurious wakeups from the pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() functions may occur. Since the return from pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably suffering from spurious wakes and some problem with the junk counter. I just removed that counter and added a cond wait loop function (and a little lock context manager) and then the hangings seems to have stopped.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>

#define BUFFER_LIMIT 20

struct struktura{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t bufferNotFull;
    pthread_cond_t bufferNotEmpty;
    int bufferIndex;
    char * buffer;
};

// a lock context manager
class mlock {
    pthread_mutex_t* mtx;
public:
    mlock(pthread_mutex_t& Mtx) :
        mtx(&Mtx)
    {
        int rv=pthread_mutex_lock(mtx);
        if(rv) throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(rv));
    }
    mlock(const mlock&) = delete;
    mlock(mlock&&) = delete;
    mlock& operator=(const mlock&) = delete;
    mlock& operator=(mlock&&) = delete;
    ~mlock() {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mtx);
    }
};

// silly loop to take care of spurious wakes
void cwait(pthread_cond_t& c, pthread_mutex_t& m, std::function<bool()> f) {
    while(f()) pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);
}

void* funProducent(void *arg){
    struktura* data = static_cast<struktura*>(arg);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 100) {
        mlock dummy(data->mutex);
        cwait(data->bufferNotFull, data->mutex, [&](){return data->bufferIndex == BUFFER_LIMIT - 1;});

        int randomValue = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        if( randomValue < 13 ){
            data->buffer[++data->bufferIndex] = 'a';
            printf("%2d : Producent at index %d added %c\n", i, data->bufferIndex, data->buffer[data->bufferIndex]);
            i++;
            pthread_cond_signal(&data->bufferNotEmpty);
        }
    }
    printf("producent is done\n");
    return nullptr;
}

void* funKonzument(void *arg){
    struktura* data = static_cast<struktura*>(arg);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 100) {
        mlock dummy(data->mutex);
        cwait(data->bufferNotEmpty, data->mutex, [&](){return data->bufferIndex<0;});

        printf("\t\t\t%2d : Konzument at index %d consumed %c\n", i, data->bufferIndex, data->buffer[data->bufferIndex]);
        data->bufferIndex--;
        i++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&data->bufferNotFull);
    }
    printf("\t\t\tkonzument is done\n");
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threadProducent, threadKonzument;
    struktura threadData;
    threadData.buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_LIMIT);
    threadData.bufferIndex = -1;
    threadData.bufferNotFull = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    threadData.bufferNotEmpty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    threadData.mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    pthread_create(&threadProducent, NULL, funProducent, &threadData);
    pthread_create(&threadKonzument, NULL, funKonzument, &threadData);

    pthread_join(threadProducent, NULL);
    pthread_join(threadKonzument, NULL);

    free(threadData.buffer);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&threadData.mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&threadData.bufferNotFull);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&threadData.bufferNotEmpty);
    return 0;
}
```